# Which database scheme is better for performance aspect?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, query-optimization

----Scheme1----

```
CREATE TABLE college (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(250),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE student (
college INT NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(100),
FOREIGN KEY (college) REFERENCES college(id),
CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (college,username)
);

CREATE TABLE subject (
college INT NOT NULL,
id INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(100),
FOREIGN KEY (college) REFERENCES college(id),
CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (college,id)
);

CREATE TABLE marks (
college INT NOT NULL,
student VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
subject INT NOT NULL,
marks INT NOT NULL,
// forget about standard for this example
FOREIGN KEY (college) REFERENCES college(id),
FOREIGN KEY (student) REFERENCES student(username),
FOREIGN KEY (subject) REFERENCES subject(id),
CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (college,subject,student)
);
```

----Scheme2----

```
CREATE TABLE college (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(250),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE student (
college INT NOT NULL,
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(100),
FOREIGN KEY (college) REFERENCES college(id),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE subject (
college INT NOT NULL,
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(100),
FOREIGN KEY (college) REFERENCES college(id),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE marks (
student VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
subject INT NOT NULL,
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
marks INT NOT NULL,
// forget about standard for this example
FOREIGN KEY (student) REFERENCES student(id),
FOREIGN KEY (subject) REFERENCES subject(id),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Looking at the above database schemes it looks like Scheme1 will give better performance while searching for the result of a specific student and faster in filtering results but it feels like it is not in all normalized forms. While Scheme2, on the other hand, looks to be fully normal but might require more JOIN operations to fetch certain results or filter the data.

Please tell me if I'm wrong about my Schemes here, also tell me which one is better?

Comment: With respect, insisting that two different students at the same college may not have the same name is **wrong.**  People do have the same names sometime.

Comment: @O.Jones It's `username` - Not `name`. Or what am I missing?

Comment: Which normalization rules do you think are violated in the first schema?

Comment: Can't judge the schema without knowing what queries will be applied.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for Schema 2: when it comes to reference a table, it is easier done by using a single column (auto_incremented primary key in Schema 1) than a combination of columns (coumpound primary keys in Schema 1). Also, as commented by O.Jones, Schema 2 assumes that two students in the same college cannot have the same name, which does not seem sensible.

There are other issues with Schema 1, eg the foreign key that relates the marks to students is malformed (you would need a coumpound foreign keys that include the college id instead of just the student name).

With properly defined foreign keys referencing primary keys, performance will not be a problem; joins perform good in this situation.

But one flaw should be fixed in Schema 2, that is to store a reference to the college in the marks table. You don't need this, since a student belongs to a college (there is a reference to the college in the student table).

Also, I am unsure that a subject should belong to a college: isn't it possible that the same subject would be taught in different colleges?

Finally, I would suggest giving clearer names to the foreign key columns, like `student_id` instead of `student`, and `college_id` instead of `college`.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to assess whether a schema is normalized without first knowing the the relationships between entities.  Can a student be associated with only one college? Can a student be associated multiple times over with the same subject, getting different marks?

Declaring foreign keys maintains referential integrity but slows down insertions and updates.  You can get the same functionality without declaring the fks, but you may end up with some orphaned records.  The fact that a particular index is used for a fk, or not, makes no difference to SELECT query performance.

JOIN operations use indexes. So do fks. So if you have the correct indexes, your JOIN operations will be efficient. But it's impossible to know which indexes are the best without knowing your JOIN queries.

Conventionally, each table's `id` column comes first.  And many designers name each `id` column after the table in which it appears, for example `college.college_id` rather than `college.id`. That makes JOIN queries slightly easier to read.

You should use a surrogate primary key in the `student` table (`student.student_id`) rather than using the student's name as part of the primary key. JOINing on `id` values is faster than joining on `VARCHAR()` values.  And, some students may share names.  (In the real world, peoples's dates of birth accompany their names in tables: it helps tell people apart.)

I think your `marks` table should contain these columns:

```
CREATE TABLE marks (
  student_id INT NOT NULL,
  subject_id INT NOT NULL,
  marks INT NOT NULL,
  // foreign keys as needed
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id, subject_id)
);
```

Can a student have multiple marks for the same subject? In that case use a `marks_id` as the pk instead of `(student_id, subject_id)`.